# Test instance's id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this integration spec:

```
describe '#new' do
    let(:location){ FactoryGirl.build(:location) }

    before { visit new_location_path }
    context 'when using valid values' do
        it 'redirects to show the new location' do
            fill_in 'location_latitude', with: location.latitude
            fill_in 'location_longitude', with: location.longitude
            fill_in 'location_radius', with: location.radius
            click_button('Create')

            current_path.should eq "/locations/1"               
        end
    end
end
```

And this failure:

```
1) LocationsController#new when using valid values redirects to show the new location
   Failure/Error: current_path.should eq "/locations/1"

   expected: "/locations/1"
        got: "/locations/2658"

   (compared using ==)
```

This is because the database' id is autoincrementing, and even thought the location is the first record to be saved in the locations table, it has an id of 2658.

So how should I fix this problem? I could truncate the table, but this is slow and still a bit fiddly.

```
config.before(:all) { DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation } # stop the ID autoincrementing }

config.before(:each) do 
    DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

I'd still have to count how many locations have been saved to the table to know their id. (If there are 5 locations in a certain spec, I have to remember that the last one's id will be 6 ect...)

Answer (score 1):

Don't hard-code identifiers. Use the object. My suggestion would be to call the last `Location`:

`current_path.should eq location_path(Location.last)`